# Can a bootstrap grid partially collapse?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap's grid system. I have sections as follows.

```
A1 A2 A3
B1 B2 B3 B4
```

The A's are wide and the B's are narrow. I would like it to collapse on a narrow screen to:

```
A1
A2
A3
B1 B2 
B3 B4
```

In other words I don't want all the Bs on separate rows if there is room. On a really small display though it should collapse to having each B on a separate row. Is this possible?

Here's a simple example

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        Long test here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        Long test here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        Long test here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        short
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        short
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        short
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        short
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GrimRob/e3wtm3z8/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xdL5ywm7/1/**

It depends on what you mean by narrow screen. You can simply change `col-sm-4` to `col-md-4` in your first `.row` and under 992px that will be full width. In the second `.row` change all the `col-sm-3` to `col-xs-6 col-sm-3` and add a responsive utility clearfix after 12 columns for that breakpoint.  See the docs and the demo link.

```
col-sm is 768px and up
col-md is 992px and up
col-lg is 1200px and up
```

If you just have a `.col-md-*` under 992px that column will be full width.

Your fiddle didn't match the code in your question, I didn't fix that.

Comment: thanks, forgot to save my code I have now, but your example trumps it anyway.